# Count number number of rows until value is reached and do this within specific ranged within a dataset

Tags: r, excel, matlab

I'm a beginner R user (not entirely sure if it's the most appropriate language for this use) and am having difficulty coming up with a solution for what I think is probably relatively easy.

EDIT - The first 60 frames of my data look as follows:

```
structure(list(Filename = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("BJB1NRL.mat", "DJG1NRL.mat", 
"DMA1NRL.mat", "DWS1NRL.mat", "EJC1NRL.mat", "FMB1NRL.mat", "GPC1NRL.mat", 
"GZZ1NRL.mat", "JMC1NRL.mat", "JTH1NRL.mat", "KAN1NRL.mat", "MAS1NRL.mat", 
"MFM1NRL.mat", "MJU1NRL.mat", "OVK1NRL.mat", "PCA1NRL.mat", "RHG1NRL.mat", 
"RHM1NRL.mat", "RJS1NRL.mat", "SIS1NRL.mat", "SXV1NRL.mat", "TXN1NRL.mat"
), class = "factor"), Label = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = "V", class = "factor"), 
    seg_Start = c(231.537, 231.537, 231.537, 231.537, 231.537, 
    231.537, 231.537, 231.537, 231.537, 231.537, 231.537, 231.537, 
    231.537, 231.537, 231.537, 231.537, 231.537, 231.537, 231.537, 
    231.537, 231.537, 231.537, 554.141, 554.141, 554.141, 554.141, 
    554.141, 554.141, 554.141, 554.141, 554.141, 554.141, 554.141, 
    554.141, 554.141, 554.141, 554.141, 554.141, 554.141, 554.141, 
    554.141, 554.141, 554.141, 554.141, 554.141, 554.141, 554.141, 
    554.141, 554.141, 554.141, 554.141, 554.141, 554.141, 554.141, 
    554.141, 554.141, 554.141, 1081.457, 1081.457, 1081.457), 
    seg_End = c(444.039, 444.039, 444.039, 444.039, 444.039, 
    444.039, 444.039, 444.039, 444.039, 444.039, 444.039, 444.039, 
    444.039, 444.039, 444.039, 444.039, 444.039, 444.039, 444.039, 
    444.039, 444.039, 444.039, 887.246, 887.246, 887.246, 887.246, 
    887.246, 887.246, 887.246, 887.246, 887.246, 887.246, 887.246, 
    887.246, 887.246, 887.246, 887.246, 887.246, 887.246, 887.246, 
    887.246, 887.246, 887.246, 887.246, 887.246, 887.246, 887.246, 
    887.246, 887.246, 887.246, 887.246, 887.246, 887.246, 887.246, 
    887.246, 887.246, 887.246, 1269.05, 1269.05, 1269.05), t_ms = c(230L, 
    240L, 250L, 260L, 270L, 280L, 290L, 300L, 310L, 320L, 330L, 
    340L, 350L, 360L, 370L, 380L, 390L, 400L, 410L, 420L, 430L, 
    440L, 550L, 560L, 570L, 580L, 590L, 600L, 610L, 620L, 630L, 
    640L, 650L, 660L, 670L, 680L, 690L, 700L, 710L, 720L, 730L, 
    740L, 750L, 760L, 770L, 780L, 790L, 800L, 810L, 820L, 830L, 
    840L, 850L, 860L, 870L, 880L, 890L, 1080L, 1090L, 1100L), 
    CPP = c(0, 0, 19.553, 16.063, 18.09, 21.547, 21.37, 21.616, 
    18.125, 20.936, 20.134, 23.642, 23.319, 24.674, 22.299, 22.587, 
    27.477, 25.924, 20.166, 20.195, 16.807, 18.189, 16.843, 16.07, 
    20.384, 26.11, 26.536, 28.891, 26.769, 27.622, 28.303, 24.373, 
    22.043, 23.579, 26.797, 26.384, 29.34, 31.437, 31.531, 24.404, 
    22.396, 26.416, 28.531, 26.735, 28.796, 28.494, 27.177, 27.325, 
    26.273, 29.066, 24.344, 21.124, 28.363, 24.193, 19.815, 11.897, 
    14.125, 0, 0, 22.398)), .Names = c("Filename", "Label", "seg_Start", 
"seg_End", "t_ms", "CPP"), row.names = c(NA, 60L), class = "data.frame")
```

What I have to do is straightfoward to do manually, but I'm struggling to create a script to do it for me.
For each time segment (i.e. 231-444, then 1081-1269 etc) I need to see how many milliseconds it takes for the value in the final column (CPP) to reach a threshold value (e.g. 28).
That is, I need to count how many rows from the segment starting (t_ms = seg_Start) until the value in the final row reaches this threshold value, since each row is 10ms.
If the value never reaches the threshold then a value of 0 should be given.

So far, my code is mostly my attempts to split the dataset up accordingly to be analysed. It is likely inefficient, and more worringly, incorrect.

EDIT - for clarification - I need to analyse the 'CPP' values for each "segment" separately, for each different 'Filename'. One segment is the values in 't_ms' between 'seg_Start' and 'seg_End'.

For example, for the first segment for the first filename, my answer would be '280ms' - each row is 10ms. The first time CPP reaches 28 in the time segment between the first seg_start - seg_End is in row 28 (value = 28.891). 10 x 28 = 280ms.

**FINAL EDIT** Removed extraneous datasets. Left parts relevant to question only.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## EDIT:

I edited your data to include two different file names as follows.

```
df$Filename[15:17] <- "DMA1NRL.mat"
```

time.2.threshold is a function that takes three arguments: df - data, threshold - CPP threshold, time_factor - number in ms.

Inside the function, there are three loops. First loop takes care of data for a file name. The second loop takes care of values in seg_Start and the third innermost loop works on the data frame obtained through the second loop and sorts the data frame for CPP column and find the minimum row value (row index) takes to reach the CPP threshold and above.

time_2_threshold is time_factor * rows_CPP_to_threshold

Finally, time.2.threshold function returns a data frame with the filename,  seg_Start, seg_End, rows_CPP_to_threshold, total_rows and time_2_threshold values for the entire data frame.

I am still trying to understand what is your expectation, because it is not obvious from your question yet, however the steps are coded properly. People may suggest some idiomatic R version of this code that may improve performance, but I am not doing it here, because it is still not yet clear what are your expectations. Hope this helps!

```
time.2.threshold <- function(df = df, threshold = 25, time_factor = 10){
  
  df_threshold <- data.frame(filename = character(),
                             seg_Start = numeric(),
                             seg_End = numeric(),
                             rows_CPP_to_threshold = numeric(),
                             total_rows = numeric(),
                             time_2_threshold = numeric(),
                             stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
  
  for(df_file in unique(df$Filename)){
    
    df_filename <- df[which(df$Filename == df_file), ]
    
    for (i in unique(df$seg_Start)){
      
      start_df <- df_filename[which(df_filename$seg_Start == i), ]
      
      seg_End_unique <- unique(start_df$seg_End)
      
      if(length(seg_End_unique) > 0 ){
        
        for(j in seg_End_unique){
          
          df1 <- start_df[which(start_df$seg_End == j), ]
          
          #df1 <- df1[with(df1, order(CPP)),]
          
          df1_CPP_index = which(df1$CPP >= threshold)
          
          if( length(df1_CPP_index) > 0 && !is.na(df1_CPP_index) && !is.nan(df1_CPP_index) ){
            rows_CPP_to_threshold <- min(df1_CPP_index)
          }else{
            rows_CPP_to_threshold <- NA
          }
          
          total_rows = nrow(df1)
          
          df2 <- data.frame(filename = df_file,
                            seg_Start = i,
                            seg_End = j,
                            rows_CPP_to_threshold = rows_CPP_to_threshold,
                            total_rows = total_rows,
                            time_2_threshold = time_factor*rows_CPP_to_threshold,
                            stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
          
          df_threshold <- rbind(df_threshold, df2 )
        }    
      }else
        next
    }
  }
  return(df_threshold)
}

df_threshold <- time.2.threshold(df = df, threshold = 15, time_factor = 10)
```

output

```
df_threshold <- time.2.threshold(df = df, threshold = 15, time_factor = 10)

    print(df_threshold)
     filename seg_Start  seg_End rows_CPP_to_threshold total_rows time_2_threshold
1 BJB1NRL.mat   231.537  444.039                     3         19               30
2 BJB1NRL.mat   554.141  887.246                     1         35               10
3 BJB1NRL.mat  1081.457 1269.050                     3          3               30
4 DMA1NRL.mat   231.537  444.039                     1          3               10
```

After commenting out the sorting of CPP column:

```
df_threshold <- time.2.threshold(df = df, threshold = 25, time_factor = 10)
print(df_threshold)
     filename seg_Start  seg_End rows_CPP_to_threshold total_rows time_2_threshold
1 BJB1NRL.mat   231.537  444.039                    15         19              150
2 BJB1NRL.mat   554.141  887.246                     4         35               40
3 BJB1NRL.mat  1081.457 1269.050                    NA          3               NA
4 DMA1NRL.mat   231.537  444.039                     3          3               30
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I can see what it is that you've done and how efficient it can be in the end. However, I think I wasn't clear about what it is I need to measure, apologies.

My dataset it approximately 18,000 rows, split into 22 different 'filenames' (these filenames are different people, so need to be analysed separately).

For each time between the seg_Start and seg_End (i.e. in the first example from 230ms < t_ms < 440ms), I need to see how long in ms (i.e. how many rows) until the value in column first reaches CPP.

This needs to be done for each different seg_Start-seg_End.

Comment: Provide some of your data using this command, so it will be easier to work with.. dput(head(df, 50)) will output the first 50 rows of your data. copy and paste the output in your question above.

Comment: If I understand correctly, you first read your data from a .csv file into a data frame with a name of "Result". if this is true, you need to use dput(head(Result, 50)) to provide the first 50 rows of your data.

Comment: @Linguistable See my answer above. The code assumes that you have a single file name in the data set. If you have multiple file names, this code can be easily tweaked to accommodate them as well.

Comment: Thanks Sathish. Your above code gets me so frustratingly close to what I'm looking for.

I can see that the output values in time_2_threshold are the rows that have the first instance of when CPP reaches the threshold. This contains the information I need, I think, but isn't quite there! I can see when I View() in RStudio that the time_2_threshold value has the row.name of the original row in the df (e.g. the first time_2_threshold value of 21 has row.name of 18). It is this original row.name that I need, as this tells me how long in ms it took.

I'll keep trying to tweak in the meantime...

Comment: Oh, in addition, it is not the minimum value closest to the threshold that is required. Rather the first time the CPP value reaches or is above the threshold. In the data given, row 17 (CPP value 27.477) would be the correct value. Row 18 (CPP value 25.924) is closer to the threshold, but row 17 reached the threshold first.

The point being, I want to time how long (count how many rows) it takes for the CPP value to reach the threshold. And do this for each unique segment.

Your code so far gets me almost there!

Comment: @Linguistable see my edited solution have support for multiple file names as well and in the output rows_CPP_to_threshold indicate that the row at which CPP value reached the threshold. Programmatically, you get the minimum value of the index, but literally it the value when CPP first reached the threshold

Comment: @Linguistable : time_2_threshold is the value when you multiply "rows_CPP_to_threshold" with 10 ms  i.e., time_factor you have chosen.

Comment: It makes sense, however, that is the number of rows it takes to get CPP value to reach threshold once it has been put in order. I need to know how long it takes to reach threshold in the original order in the original dataframe. So in the 60 example rows I have given, the time_2_threshold (of threshold = 25) would be 170ms (i.e. 17th row x 10). I think it is because the CPP column is sorted in order that creates the incorrect values.

Comment: @Linguistable So, it means you have data previously ordered by some means. See my edit above. I simply commented out the line that does the sorting. You can remove it if you feel it is extraneous

Comment: I had tried that, however, unfortunately this gives a value of '17' for every row for the whole dataset, except those for which NA is correct.

Comment: Is this you are expecting from the file name BJB1NRL.mat: 231.537-444.039 = 15; 554.141- 887.246 = 4. Remember, I edited the file name for row 15,16,17. So the row 18 becomes row 15 for BJB1NRL.mat

Comment: Sorry, not exactly sure what you mean. I've updated the original question with an output of what I get using your latest code on my whole dataset. Commenting out the line that does the sorting makes every value 17.
As I said, I feel like your help has got me so close to the answer, but hard to get the correct answer.

Comment: There is a bug in my code. I used the df data frame instead of start_df for creating df1 data frame. See line 25. I just corrected it

Comment: Perfect! Works exactly as I need it to. If I wasn't a beginner, I probably would have picked that up ages ago. Thank you, Sathish, for your patience and your persistence.

Comment: If you feel I answered your question, please accept it. Before doing it, please edit your question and remove extra data sets. It is very confusing the way you frame your question. I am glad I helped you with this problem :)